# Get Selected Section in Hub element on Windows Phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8, selecteditem, section508

How can I get the selected section in a Hub element in a Windows Phone 8 app? I use the SectionsInViewChanged event from the hub but this is only fired one time when the app is started. If i change the Hub section I don't get the event. Where can I react if the Hub section is changed?